# force generic type of template function to inherit some class

Tags: c++

in Rust programing language you can declare a function with argument of generic type that must implement a trait. (for those who doesn't know, you can think `implement` is `inheritance` and `trait` is `class`). so the object you pass to that function must have that trait implemented. for example:

```rs
// Define a function `printer` that takes a generic type `T` which
// must implement trait `Display`.
fn printer<T: Display>(t: T) {
    println!("{}", t);
}
```

now my question is, how can I define such template function in c++ that force a type to inherit some base classes?

Comment: can you use C++20?

Comment: c++20 has concepts. In earlier version of standard you should use SFINAE to limit T to meet specific requirement.

Comment: typically you would not require inheritance, but rather require that `T` has certain members

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number would you answer for both "yes I can" and "no I can't"

Comment: Use `std::is_base_of` together with either SFINAE or C++20's concepts?

Comment: @MarekR SFINAE? what is that?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Good. I will search for both of them. tnx

Comment: Technique used by answers below (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error). This term is a bit wider then examples below.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it was interesting: >"typically you would not require inheritance, but rather require that T has certain members "so how can I do this?

Comment: I don't know rust, in C++ a type trait is generally a template that given a type produces either a value or type. In below answer `std::is_base_of_v` is a trait specifically to check if one class is base of another, there are many others (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) and its not too difficult to write your own. In the answers below you can replace `std::is_base_of_v` with some other trait. For example you could require that `T` is a pointer type (via https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++20 way:

```
template <std::derived_from<Display> T>
void printer(const T &value)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or the abbreviated template syntax:

```
void printer(const std::derived_from<Display> auto &value)
{
    // ...
}
```

Do note that there's some difference between `std::derived_from` and `std::is_base_of_v` (other than one of them being a concept): the latter checks for any base, while the former checks for an unambiguous public base. If that's what you want, but you don't have C++20, you can additionally check `std::is_convertible_v<A *, B *>` for this.

Comment: thank you for your help. as I saw in document, if derivative is protected or private, `derived_from` returns false. why?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) to check if a type has a particular base class.  Leveraging [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) that would look like:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<BASE_CLASS, T>, bool> = true>
ret_type function_name(T t)
{
    // your code
}
```

The above template will only get instantiated if `T` derives from `BASE_CLASS` or is the same type.

Answer (score 1):

In C++20, you have `requires` that simplifies this.
Since C++20 is not yet that widespreaded at the time of writing, here's an example that's backwards compatible:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Display, T>> fn(const T& t)
{
    // your favorite println implementation over t
}
```

If you'd like to return a value, use `std::enable_if_t<condition, return_type>`.